# Unable to update in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to update my database with the following code:

```
const patchParams = {
  TableName: 'users',
  Key: {
      email,
  },
  UpdateExpression: `set oauth_tokens.oauth_token1 = :a`,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':a': accessToken,
  },
  ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
};

dynamoDb.update(patchParams, (putError, result) => {
  console.log(putError, result);
```

But it keeps throwing this error: 
`The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update',
  code: 'ValidationException'`

I think it might be because there's no `email` field populated yet. Is there a way to both put a new entry and update it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two errors here.

The first is your key. All of the code samples in the AWS documentation (like [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.03), for example) would have you use

```
Key: {
    'email': email,
},
```

The second issue is that if this item is new (not already in the database), you can’t use `oauth_tokens.oauth_token1` as a document path. `oauth_tokens` doesn’t exist yet, so it’s invalid to try to directly reference one of its children.

Instead, you should use

```
UpdateExpression: 'set oauth_tokens = :a',
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':a': { 'oauth_token1': accessToken },
},
```